# Computing Feature Importance with OneHotEncoded Features

Tags: scikit-learn

Is it possible to compute feature importance (with Random Forest) in scikit learn when features have been onehotencoded?

Comment: Yes, depending on what transformer you use for your one-hot encoding (e.g. `DictVectorizer`) you could access the feature names from that transformer using the `feature_names_` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of how to combine feature names with their importances:

```python
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline


# some example data
X = pd.DataFrame({'feature': ['value1', 'value2', 'value2', 'value1', 'value2']})
y = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]

# translate rows to dicts
def row_to_dict(X, y=None):
    return X.apply(dict, axis=1)

# define prediction model
ft = FunctionTransformer(row_to_dict, validate=False)
dv = DictVectorizer()
rf = RandomForestClassifier()

# glue steps together
model = make_pipeline(ft, dv, rf)

# train
model.fit(X, y)

# get feature importances
feature_importances = zip(dv.feature_names_, rf.feature_importances_)

# have a look
print feature_importances
```

Comment: This is great! This returns the feature importance of each feature per label, I didn't think this was possible! Thank you :)

Comment: Is there a straightforward way to get the overall Feature Importance of each feature? (not for each label)

Comment: Yes, you could aggregate them, e.g. mean, median etc